# Cocos 2D - parsing a list of sequences using CCCallFunc

Tags: lua, cocos2d-x

I want to have a sequence of actions, that are performed on different nodes. For this, I want to handle each action as an individual sequence of that action, and a CCCallFunc which points to a function that controls the sequence of actions.

Currently I am attempting to get the code to work on just one node, but unfortunately I keep getting an error I cannot figure out.

Below is the code that builds the array of sequences. For every time moveEast() is called, a new sequence is added to actionArray.

```
actionArray = {}

function moveEast()
    local posAction = CCMoveBy:create(0.2, cc.p(-47, 0))

    local callback = CCCallFunc:create(handleActions)
    actionArray[table.getn(actionArray) + 1] = {posAction, callback}
end
```

The referenced function in CCCallFunc is called directly, to kickstart the process of parsing the list of sequences.

```
actionCounter = 0

handleActions = function ()
    if actionCounter < table.getn(actionArray) then
        actionCounter = actionCounter + 1

        local actionSeq = actionArray[actionCounter]

        layerMaze:runAction(actionSeq)
    end
end

... lots of code ...

handleActions()
```

The CCCallFunc in the sequence works fine, and handleActions() is called, but when there is more than one sequence in actionArray, and I get the following error:

```
cocos2d: [LUA-print] ----------------------------------------
cocos2d: [LUA-print] LUA ERROR: ASSERT FAILED ON LUA EXECUTE: Argument must be non-nil

cocos2d: [LUA-print] stack traceback:
    [string "src/main.lua"]:13: in function <[string "src/main.lua"]:10>
    [C]: in function 'runAction'
    [string "GameScene.lua"]:312: in function <[string "GameScene.lua"]:304>
cocos2d: [LUA-print] ----------------------------------------
```

When running in a debugger, I can see that all the variables are available when calling handleActions() through CCCallFunc.

Anybody out there have any idea of what is wrong?

**Update 1**

I was in an interactive console of the debugger testing by a calling the function setTag() on the actionSeq variable, which holds the sequence, within the handleActions() function.

The first sequence in the actionArray can easily set the tag, but the second sequence returns the following error:

```
=>actionSeq:setTag(2)
Execution error 206: [string "debugger"]:0: invalid 'cobj' in function 'lua_cocos2dx_Action_setTag'
```

The best i can gather from that error message, is that it has something to do with the garbage collector or variable scope across threads. I tried to disable the garbage collector using collectgarbage('stop'), but it had no affect.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `table.getn(tbl)` instead of `#tbl`?

Comment: No other than I am new to Lua, and did not know that particular notation.